# How to clear history in Office 365 "My Office" Application?

Tags: privacy

See screen snapshot below.  When I open "My Office" I don't want my history to show up.  How to disable this "feature"?  Also, I don't want my document history copied to a cloud database on timelines.

[image: Click here to see Screen Snapshot]

Comment: Open your OneDrive web page, click Recent folder, clear the recent list in Recent folder. Then check if your files can be removed from Recent list in My Office application.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want my document history copied to a cloud database on timelines.

The document list displayed within My Office is not uploaded to the cloud.  The document list within My Office is only generated, by the Recent document list of each Office application installed on your system.  In order to remove a document from the Recent document list within My Office, you must remove the document, from the list of Recent documents of the applicable Office application.  This requires starting Word, Excel, OneNote, and any other Office application you have recently opened.

In order to accomplish that, within the File, right-click a document and select "Clear unpinned Documents" or "Clear unpinned Workbooks" or "Clear unpinned items" depending on the Office application.  Once you have done that for each Office you have recently used, close My Office, and restart it.

[image]

This, by the way, is the only way to clear the list within My Office.